# RegEx Pattern for Exactly Three Spaces and Comma Delimited Doubles

Tags: regex, geometry

This is a very odd request, but I can't seem to find any examples that are helping me out. I need a regex pattern that matches the following:

```
(0.0 0.0,1.0 1.0,2.0 0.0,0.0 0.0)
```

It's essentially a triangle on a geometric plane where each point would be:

1. 0.0 0.0
2. 1.0 1.0
3. 2.0 0.0
4. 0.0 0.0

The 4th point being the original starting point. I need the regex patter to look for the parenthesis, integers, dots, commas and exactly three spaces.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how my question does not present a "clear problem statement". I think it's very clear. I needed a regex pattern that would match the my example code. I got that with @alphabravo's answer. Are regex or spatial related questions not allowed on Stack?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this long pattern

```
\((\d*(?:\.\d+)?\s\d*(?:\.\d+)?),(?!\1)(\d*(?:\.\d+)?\s\d*(?:\.\d+)?),(?!\1)(?!\2)(\d*(?:\.\d+)?\s\d*(?:\.\d+)?),(\1)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/19)